# JPEG with incomplete MCUs - padding method

Tags: encoding, jpeg

Based on comments from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791309/187650 I made a question about it as it is not clear yet.

I have a bitmap of 9px (width) x 17px (height) RGB.
The goal is to encode it as jpeg using halve chroma subsampling in vertical direction with quality default (50) using 3 components.

For the halve chroma subsampling in vertical direction I should use an MCU with 8x16 (width x height).

Steps I do:

1. convert RGB to YCbCr image (3 components: Y, Cb, Cr).
2. make 2dim. array of the Y, Cb and Cr components bigger so that I can create full 8x16 MCU blocks.
3. split in MCU blocks of 8x16 --> get Y0Y1CbCr 8x8 blocks
4. use the Y0Y1CbCr 8x8 blocks to DCT
5. ...

In step 2 I'm having for Y, Cb and Cr a 2dim. array size of [17, 9].
I calculate how many rows and columns I should add to have full MCU blocks of 8x16 and as a result I create a new array of size [32, 16] with the original values of the smaller array.

Now is the problem: how do I padd or fill the extra values, because the new array is bigger.

1. padding with zeros (0's) ?
2. padding with ones (1's) ?
3. padding with last row and last column? (first pad row or first columns?)
4. padding with another value?

Original bitmap:

[image: original bitmap]

Result padding with zeros:

[image: padding zeros]

Result padding with ones:

[image: padding with ones]

As you can see the result gives a green color at the bottom when padding with 0 or 1.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You kind of went off the rails at step 2 in your original list. There should be no arrays bigger than 8x8 for the DCT processing. You need to subsample your original image into 8x8 blocks for Y0,Y1,Cb,Cr (four unique 8x8 blocks). When pulling the pixel data from the source image to fill those blocks, you will pad the missing pixels (if needed). Then do the DCT transform on each, zigzag and Huffman encode.

Comment: I did not make the DCT bigger than 8x8.  If my image is 9x17 px then my Y, Cb, Cr is an array of 9x17. So I make this array bigger  (padd it with a value) and take 8x8 values (or other depending on sampling ratio). 
That should give the same result no?

Comment: I've found it easier to not do it that way. In my encoder, I do the color conversion and subsampling at the same time and write the results into the 8x8 DCT blocks ready to go. Your idea will be slower (writing/reading additional temporary data) and harder to scale to all cases.

Comment: The usual method of padding MCUs is to duplicate the last row and column.